Present simple or future conditional
While writing a research proposal, I encountered the following issue. Consider the following two variants:

Present simple:


I would like to measure X. Finding evidence that X is large is helpful to validate hypothesis Y.


Future conditional:


I would like to measure X. Finding evidence that X is large would be helpful to validate hypothesis Y.

Which one is correct or more appropriate?

On the one hand, present simple does seem like a fine choice to me. Hypothesis Y predicts that X is large. Therefore I am simply stating an implication, and thus a fact: "Finding evidence that X is large" -> "Hypothesis Y is (partially) validated"

On the other hand, several people pointed out to me that there is a convention to use the future conditional. Arguably, it does seem like it reads a bit smoother. But I was not able to find an explicit reference for such a convention. Note that this version does not state anything that is wrong, but rather just states a weaker version of a true statement (It is always true that finding evidence that X is large is helpful to validate hypothesis Y.)

This guideline for academic writing states that present simple is used for facts. However, in a later example (under "Future simple") it also suggests that in my case future conditional would be the correct choice. So the issue might be what exactly constitutes a fact and what not.



'Finding that X is true adds credibility to the theory ...' strongly suggests that such evidence has been / is being found, ie it is known that such evidence exists. If such evidence is only a hope, the conditional should be used.

2 sounds more natural to me. You can also use the simple future "will be".

But I would change "to validate" to "in validating".

Your first example would be simpler with something like "I want to measure X. Finding evidence that X is large will help to validate hypothesis Y."  If you start with "I would like to measure X" then it seems natural to continue in the same mood.
